# multiline row with dynamic row height in grid in vaadin 8

Tags: vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I am using Vaadin 8. In grid, I have multiple columns, where cells corresponding to one column can have multiple lines. I am able to show the multiple lines using following approach

```
referenceGrid.addColumn(questionAnswerSummary -> 
         questionAnswerSummary.getAnswersList()
        ,new HtmlRenderer())
   .setCaption(ANSWER_COLUMN + "1");
```

where getAnswersList have data with `<br>`

But now the row height does not adjust itself.
How can I adjust the row heights depending on the number of lines in rows or is there any other way to show the multi line in rows.

P.S I was able to achieve the above when I was using vaadin 7.  I used verticallayout component as the column type.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with Vaadin 8 `Grid` and the Vaadin 7 `Table` wasn't migrated. As far as I know `Grid` has fixed size row height which you can set.